# 4-momentum as $m\frac{ds}{d\tau}$

Tags: special-relativity, momentum, velocity, units

I have read that the 4-momentum of a particle with trajectory $s^\mu(t)=(ct,\vec{x}(t))$ can be expressed as $m\frac{ds}{d\tau}$.

In the particle's rest frame we get

$$
m\frac{ds^\mu}{d\tau}=m\frac{ds^\mu}{dt}=(mc,m\dot{\vec{x}}(t))
$$

However, $mc$ has dimension $\text{mass}\frac{\text{length}}{\text{time}}$, whereas energy (the 4-momentum's time component) has dimension $\text{mass}\frac{\text{length}^2}{\text{time}^2}$

What's the exact problem here? Does one multiply the time component of the 4-momentum by $c$ again, so $s^\mu(t)=(c^2t,\vec{x}(t))$? Or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: The conventional [4-momentum vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-momentum) is $(E/c, p_x, p_y, p_z)$. The $1/c$ corrects the units for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time component of the four-momentum *should not* have energy units. We can probably agree that four-momentum should transform as a Lorentz vector under Lorentz transformations - thus the "first"/"zeroth"/"timelike" component and the "spacelike" components can get mixed. This is only possible if all the components have the same units (because the Lorentz transformation is free of units). Thus there is no problem here at all - the components of the four-momentum vector in any system do all have units of momentum.